# "true && E" returns "E" in Scala?

Tags: scala

In the course on *Scala* at Coursera (lecture 1.4, around 3 mins), *Martin Odersky* says that the expression `true && e` always returns `e` (e is any object). And the expression `false || e` also returns `e`. He explains that sometimes the last expression is not always evaluated.

But when I run these expressions I get `error: type mismatch`.
For `true && 5` I get `found: Int(5); required: Boolean`

Has Scala evolved in recent times or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`e` stands for *boolean expression*.

```
Predicate: a boolean expression to be evaluated e.g. (x >= 4), (x != 0), etc
```

see https://sites.google.com/a/stonybrook.edu/functional-programming-scala/lecture-1-4

---

From the [Scala Reference book](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf), paragraph 6.16 **Conditional expressions**, given:

```
if (e1) e2 else e3
```

> The condition e1 is expected to conform to type Boolean. The then-part
>   e2 and the else-part e3 are both expected to conform to the expected
>   type of the conditional expression. The type of the conditional
>   expression is the weak least upper bound (§3.5.3) of the types of e2
>   and e3.

Comment: Well, Odersky said that `e` can be any object

Comment: @Graduate: source, please.

Comment: Lecture 1.4, around 3 mins

Comment: @Graduate: `e` is not any object, is any expression with result type `Boolean`, for instance `{println("text"); 1 == 2}`.